# Bootstrap columns alignment

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Bootstrap (v3.3.7) to design a form that contains some lines with 1 column and other lines with 2 columns:

[image]

On the line with 2 columns (`Town` and `Country`), the first field is a bit shifted to the left compared to the upper and lower lines. This is because the `Town` label has a width of `col-md-4` in a column of `col-md-6` which is different from the other labels in other lines that have a width of `col-md-2` in a column of `col-md-12`.

I chose this design so later, on a mobile view, I will add some settings to move the town underneath town.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="town" class="col-md-4 control-label">Town</label>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <input id="town" name="town" class="form-control" type="text" v-model="address.town">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="address_type" class="col-md-4 control-label">Country</label>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <select id="country_id" name="address_type" class="form-control" v-model="address.country_id">
                    <option v-for="country in countries" :value="country.id">
                        {{country.name}}
                    </option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="note" class="col-md-2 control-label">Comment</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <textarea id="note" name="note" class="form-control" v-model="address.note"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to have the same design but with aligned inputs controls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to add a row before you add columns since rows have -15px margins from left and right and columns has 15px padding from both sides so it fits to the div perfectly. also when you add a cols & rows make sure you add it inside a container. you can  override the minus margins from the rows and padding from the columns. before you check that add a row that wrap the form-group div

Comment: This works great.
It makes it to one row before the column and another row after the column like so: `<div class="row"> <div class="col-md-6"> <div class="row"> <div class="form-group">`